# Remove image cache from SDWebImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, caching, sdwebimage

I am not able to remove image cache which are cached by SDWebImage.
I am using "[UIImageView+UIActivityIndicatorForSDWebImage.h](https://github.com/JJSaccolo/UIActivityIndicator-for-SDWebImage)"
I am caching image with this code.

```
[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image_icon.png"] usingActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
```

Now sometime i want to remove cache of image because sometime same url will give me another image by server.

I am removing image cache using this code.

```
[[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] removeImageForKey:[self.imgArray objectAtIndex:indexForDelete] fromDisk:YES];
```

But is give's me error like:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryM UTF8String]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fcb01f9bf70'

How to remove cache ??

Comment: I think self.imgArray is an array of Dictionary and not array of strings.

Comment: yes i got now solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method  `- (void)removeImageForKey:(NSString *)key fromDisk:(BOOL)fromDisk` in the SDWebImage takes `NSString` as an argument.

In your above code it looks like `[self.imgArray objectAtIndex:indexForDelete]` gives you an an `NSDictionary` object and hence the crash.

So you would need something like this;

```
NSDictionary *imageDictionary = [self.imgArray objectAtIndex:indexForDelete];
NSString *cacheKeyToDelete = [imageDictionary objectForKey:@"YourKeyForImageCacheKey"];

[[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] removeImageForKey:cacheKeyToDelete fromDisk:YES];
```

Comment: A doubt I have.. If `[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image_icon.png"] usingActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];` used. Then is the imageURL key to remove from cache?

Answer (score 2):

in **swift**

```
SDImageCache.shared.removeImage(forKey: _imageURL?.description, withCompletion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, updating single image url with SDWebImageRefreshCached options.

Objective-C:

```
[self.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlStr] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"???"] options:SDWebImageRefreshCached];
```

Swift: u can translate it by method name